# magento1.9: call page without loggedin

Tags: magento1.9.2.4

I wrote code in AccountController.php for unDeleteAction function, but it is redirects to login

```
   protected function _unDeleteAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_login')->setTemplate('customer/account/undelete.phtml');
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
    }
```

But when i open this page it is opening after logged in only. Without logged in it is redirect to login page. How to do it to open this page with logged in